# Why doesn't SET IDENTITY_INSERT OFF work for me in EF 4.1?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm using Entity Framework 4.1 Code First and I have a table that has an IDENTITY key, because all new entries in this table should have an auto-generated ID (the ID column is called AccountNumber).  I need to import some data from the previous incarnation of this system - these account numbers need to be preserved.

In [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7151710/how-do-i-temporarily-turn-off-an-identity-column-in-ef-code-first), I learned I have to SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON in order to preserve the old account numbers.  The idea is that when importing old customers, I'm going to turn IDENTITY_INSERT ON, run a raw SQL insert statement, then turn it off and proceed normally using EF entities.

So, I have the following code:

```
    public const string InsertQuery = "INSERT INTO dbo.Businesses (AccountNumber, Name, Active, CreatedBy, CreatedOn, ModifiedBy, ModifiedOn) VALUES({0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}, {6})";
```

...

```
            dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Businesses ON");
            dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(InsertQuery, customerData.AccountNumber, customerData.Name, customerData.Active,
                                                 m_userContextManager.GetCurrentUserName(), Now,
                                                 m_userContextManager.GetCurrentUserName(), Now);
            dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Businesses OFF");

            // load the entity and map the rest of the attributes
            dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

When I get to executing the second statement, I get the following infuriating error (because I've just set it to OFF or so I think):

`Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Businesses' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.`

The return value from the statement is -1, but because [the documentation on MSDN for ExecuteSqlCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.executesqlcommand%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) is really inadequate, I have no idea what that means.  I would expect an exception to be thrown if the statement failed for some reason.  Does anyone know what's going on here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no need to use plain old ADO.NET; the trick is packing everything into a single command:

```
public const string InsertQuery = @"
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Businesses ON;
    INSERT INTO dbo.Businesses (AccountNumber, Name, Active, CreatedBy, CreatedOn, ModifiedBy, ModifiedOn) VALUES({0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}, {6});
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Businesses OFF;
";

dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(InsertQuery, customerData.AccountNumber, customerData.Name, customerData.Active,
                                     m_userContextManager.GetCurrentUserName(), Now,
                                     m_userContextManager.GetCurrentUserName(), Now);

// load the entity and map the rest of the attributes
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Additionally, you can drop `SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Businesses OFF` (since IDENTITY_INSERT is turned off at the end of the command anyway), and `dbContext.SaveChanges()`, as ExecuteSqlCommand executes the command immediately; it doesn't wait for SaveChanges().

Comment: Any way that I can save my entity without listing all of it's properties (again - after filling it) ???

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow your question. Do you mean to access a Business POCO right after using the method I described in my answer?

Comment: I mean, inserting the POCO that I have filled in in my code without proving it's properties one-by-one (as above). (Of course I also want to use SET IDENTITY_INSERT)

Comment: Sth like `dbContext.Database.InsertWithIdentity(myPOCO);`. Probably too much to ask... :(

Comment: Not that I know, sorry. As its name implies, `ExecuteSqlCommand` is not actually inserting anything but executing a command. Although in this case the command is a SQL INSERT, it could be anything. So yes, you need to provide values for all parameters your command will need.

Comment: Without using EF, this isn't much of a solution (in my opinion). However, what worked for me is (1) wrapping the `context.SaveChanges()` in the `ExecuteSqlCommand` statements, then (2) wrapping all of that in a SQL transaction, and (3) making sure that I set the `StoreGeneratedPattern` property in the EF designer for the model's ID to "None".

Answer (score 5):

`ExecuteSqlCommand` will open the connection, execute the sql and then close it. So your next command will execute using a different connection.

What you can do is use the plain old ADO.net classes to insert the data within a single transaction. Or script the data and execute it as [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650098/how-to-execute-an-sql-script-file-using-c/1728859#1728859)

Comment: That's so kind of them to close the connection immediately after issuing the command... ;)

Comment: @JoshKodroff :) that is by design. Usually you delay the opening the connection as possible then use it and close it immediately.