# Cannot Insert custom value into identity column - Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1, identity

I am trying to switch the identity off to insert my own value, steps I followed

1. changed the property `StoredGeneratedPattern` value to `None` for the identity column
2. changed the property `StoredGeneratedPattern` value to `None` in EDMX file by opening in xml format

Tried using the below code

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew))
{
   int k = Context.ExecuteStoreCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.client ON");
   Context.ClientInfoes.Add(testclient);
   result = Context.SaveChanges();
   int j = Context.ExecuteStoreCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.client OFF");
   scope.Complete();
}
```

but I am still receiving the error

> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table  when
>   IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF

Am I missing something? Are there any other options?

Comment: Your context says ClientInfoes, but your sQL is dbo.client.  does ClientInfoes map to client?  or a clientinfoes table?

Comment: Clientinfoes map to client, Client is the table in sql.  Without the identity the insert works fine but my requirement is to pass custom client id.

Answer (score 0):

The data is stored in the database when you call TransactionScope.Complete, not when you call ClientInfoes.Add or Context.SaveChanges. So you can see that when the insert statement is called you have already switched IDENTITY INSERT back off.

Simply rearrange things...

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew))
{
   int k = Context.ExecuteStoreCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.client ON");
   Context.ClientInfoes.Add(testclient);
   result = Context.SaveChanges();
   scope.Complete();
   int j = Context.ExecuteStoreCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.client OFF");
}
```

Better yet, do all your changes to IDENTITY_INSERT outside of the transaction since it's value is session specific (you can only have it switched on for one table per session).

Answer (score 0):

See the similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7714812/why-doesnt-set-identity-insert-off-work-for-me-in-ef-4-1).

Eranga explains:

> `ExecuteSqlCommand` will open the connection, execute the sql and then
>   close it. So your next command will execute using a different
>   connection.

The ExecuteSqlCommand method is similar to the ExecuteStoreCommand.

Daniel Liuzzi explains:

> ... the trick is packing everything into a single command...

So for example,

```
string sqlStatement = "SET IDENTITY_INSERT clientInfo ON;" +
string.Format("INSERT clientInfo (ClientInfoId, Column1, Column2) VALUES ({0}, {1}, {2}, '{3}');", testClient.ClientInfoId, testClient.Column1, testclient.Column2) +
"SET IDENTITY_INSERT clientInfo OFF";
context.ExecuteStoreCommand(sqlStatement);
```

Comment: You rally want to remove that `string.Format` and properly parameterize your command instead; otherwise you're exposing yourself to SQL injection attacks.