# Using database migration insert fixed records in particular table using entity framework

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I have table properties in my MySQL database and my requirement is it should have fixed records with some default values. I want that table should get auto filled with the help of migration in code first approch of Entity Framework. I am dealing with migration first time so I want help in the same.

My current migration is as follows:

```
public override void Up()
        {
            CreateTable(
                "dbo.properties",
                c => new
                    {
                        id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                        property_name = c.Int(nullable: false),
                        value = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 255, storeType: "nvarchar"),
                        type = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    })
                .PrimaryKey(t => t.id)
                .Index(t => t.property_name, unique: true, name: "uk_property_name");

        }

        public override void Down()
        {
            DropIndex("dbo.properties", "uk_property_name");
            DropTable("dbo.properties");
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Migrations have a [Seeding Mechanism](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-3) to populate data. Since this method runs every time you `update-database` you want to make sure the data doesn't get inserted multiple times. This is what the `AddOrUpdate` command is for, although in more complex situations you could just use standard LINQ:

```
if (!context.MyTable.Any(t => t.Id == "seedId") { // insert };
```

But I would just go with the AddOrUpdate in your scenario:

```
protected override void Seed(MyContext context)
{
    context.Properties.AddOrUpdate(x => x.Value,
        new Property() { Value = "My Prop Name 1", Property_Name = 1, Type = 1 },
        new Property() { Value = "My Prop Name 2", Property_Name = 2, Type = 2 },
        new Property() { Value = "My Prop Name 3", Property_Name = 3, Type = 1 }
        );
}
```

Note that since your id field is identity I don't include it but instead use Value to check if it already exists. If value can be duplicated or you need to control the Id you may need a different technique like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37811915/how-to-insert-identity-by-addorupdate-methode-in-seed).